# django custom filter - replace line break with line space

Tags: python, django, replace, newline

If I have a string in my django template that is formatted like:

```
Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />
```

And I want to format it like:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4
```

I want to **replace** the line breaks (< br />) with a line space, so the string is on one line.

I have looked through the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/), but I cannot find a workable replace for the custom filter.

Does anyone have any suggestions or links to a working example?

Cheers.

**EDIT - MORE CONTEXT - as requested**

The string stored in the db is:

```
Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />
```

Called in the django template is:

```
{{ education_detail.education_details_institution_name|truncatechars:20 }}
```

Displayed in the browser as:

```
Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />
```

Comment: Please add a bit more context.. Include your template and your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code to replace the line break with a line space.

the issue i had was that i did not add in the @register.filter(name='replace_linebr')

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='replace_linebr')
def replace_linebr(value):
    """Replaces all values of line break from the given string with a line space."""
    return value.replace("<br />", ' ')
```

Here is the call on the template:

```
{{ education_detail.education_details_institution_name|replace_linebr }}
```

I hope that this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe apply the builtin `striptags` or `removetags` filters?
Note `removetags` was deprecated in Django 1.8.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#removetags
(the docs both seem to note some security warnings though)

```
{% filter removetags:"br" %}
    AA<br/>
    BB<br/>
    CC<br/>
    DD<br/>
{% endfilter %}
```

or

```
{% filter striptags %}
    AA<br/>
    BB<br/>
    CC<br/>
    DD<br/>
{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but striptags and removetags removes the tags and replaces them with nothing (no spaces between actual words), so these two tags are not useable in this scenario. The output of the string would be: Line 1Line 2Line 3Line 4. I want Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4.

Comment: `removetags` was deprecated in 1.8: "Deprecated since version 1.8:
removetags cannot guarantee HTML safe output and has been deprecated due to security concerns. Consider using bleach instead."